# Error: "TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list"

Tags: python

Code:

```
words = ['apple', 'pear', 'tree']
title = 'Hi my name is Bob'


if title in words:
    #do something
```

I want to be able to check if my title contains these `words`, and if so, an action would happen but I encountered this error and I'm not really sure what it means or how to go about fixing this.

Comment: You want to check *each* word to see if it's in `title`.

Comment: As written, your code doesn't return this error. Did you instead mean to write `words in title`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you need is this :

```
 words = ['apple', 'pear', 'tree']
 title = 'Hi my name is Bob'

 if any(word.casefold() in words for word in title.split()):
    #do something
```

This splits `title` into a sequence of words at the spaces, and then checks if any of them appear in the `words` list.

Notice that it uses foldcase method to convert each word to lower case, so it would work if `apple` or `Apple` where in your `title`

If the word list or title were big or you are doing this check a lot you might find it will be more efficient to use sets :

```
 words = {'apple', 'pear', 'tree'}
 title = 'Hi my name is Bob'
 if {word.casefold() for word in title.split()} & words:
    #do something
```

This converts `title` to a set of lowercase words - and does an intersection with the `words` set. It will only `do something` if that intersection contains at least one word. If `title` and `words` have no entries in common then the intersection will be an empty set, and the condition will be False.

Comment: should be 'casefold` I will correct the answer.